# Retrieving URL parameters in the order they are passed - django

Tags: python, django, django-urls, path-parameter

I am trying to retrieve the URL parameters that are passed into the function, in the order they are acutally passed.
The reason this matters, is its a payment provider integration, which calculates a hash from concatenating the values that are passed (in the order they are passed).
So based on this, i need to access the parameters in the order they are passed in the actual URL, concatenate them and then add a MD5 key that is secret to my account to verify the request.

For example:
http://example.com/order/callback?date=20200101&currency=USD&txnid=1234567&hash=thegeneratedhas

If i access the request through request.GET I get ordered dict.

pseudo-code

```
def callback(request):
  keys_concatenated = ""
  for value in request.GET:
    if value == "hash":
      pass
    else:
      keys_concatenated = keys_concatenated + request.GET[value]
```

This generates a string like: USD202001011234567
The hash generated from the provider that the order is kept, and thus is expecting the value
20200101USD1234567

Defining the parameters within urls.py is not really something I want as the payment provider is openly saying that they might change parameters passed, and thus it would break the implementation.
I also dont know the actual order they are passing it in from time to time.

Comment: You'd better get the parameters you want either through query params, or kwargs. This way you can easily get what you want.

Comment: You can probably do that if you can access the GET URL string and split by `?`.
Now you got the exact request URL, which is in the order they were received. Accessing params through objects would get you an ordered dict, as experienced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use python's built-in `urllib.parse` and parse the URL params while also maintaining their order.

A brief example:

```py
>>> from urllib.parse import parse_qsl
>>> parse_qsl('date=20200101&currency=USD&txnid=1234567&hash=thegeneratedhas')
[('date', '20200101'), ('currency', 'USD'), ('txnid', '1234567'), ('hash', 'thegeneratedhas')]
>>>
```